# Recovering Whatsapp crypt8 file

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, encryption

I would like to re-read some old whatsapp chats that are in a .crypt8 file; I have put the database in my new phone after reinstalling the app and so on (I was already able to use this procedure for some cypt12 databases), but even using the same sim number it doesn't read the database.

Were the crypt8 files not linked to the phone number? How can I read the file?

Many thanks :)